# Enlarge the graph in display mode with highcharts graphic librairy

Tags: highcharts

I am using highchart library to display graphics.

I have so a small view display. Any person give a solution to enlarge the graphic.

Comment: Please provide a code sample...

Comment: You can use solution with highslide, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/roadrash/GqhEX/

Comment: thank you for your response

Comment: You can use any other popup set up also, like the jQuery UI Dialog function.